# Who are the sons of Hamor in Genesis 33:19?

Tags: genesis, jacob

Genesis 33:19 New International Version (NIV)

> 19 For a hundred pieces of silver,[a] he bought from the ***sons of Hamor***, the father of Shechem, the plot of ground where he pitched his tent.

In the above text the sons of Hamor are said to have sold a piece of land to Jacob,but they are not mentioned elsewhere else.

Since they seemed to be men of noteworthy who had sold a piece of land to Jacob,why are they not mentioned in the proceedings that followed Dinah's rape.Only Shechem is mentioned.

1)Negotiations for Dinah's marriage

2)Negotiations about circumcision

3)When all males are butchered by Levi & Simeon they are not mentioned at all

Are these really the sons of Hamor?

Comment: Aren't they the ones who fought the Battle of Tours?  :)

Comment: This question makes very little logical sense.

Comment: @Lucian,i see you have never asked any question,quite amazing, only thing you do is d/v my questions thank you

Comment: @collenndhlovu: No, not the only thing. I also provided this site with about 40 answers and a few hundred comments. I downvoted far fewer of your questions than I felt the need to.

Answer (score 1):

We read, in Genesis 34:19:
 והוא נכבד מכל בית אביו ("*he* [Shechem] *was the most important* [or, to be reckoned with; literally, 'being heavy'] *person in his father's household*").

So, on the basis of this Genesis passage we have a couple of options:
**(1)** Hamor had several sons, who died before Jacob's arrival time. Shechem was the only survived son. In this case, the mention to the sons of Hamor as owners of a field may be a legal title deed their heirs (wifes and/or sons?) maintained to legally 'preserve the name' of each other sons of Hemor; **(2)** Hamor had several sons, living in the Jacob's arrival time, but - for a reason not explained in the text - only Shechem, along with his father Hamor, was in charge to make important decisions for all the family. In this case, the other sons were included in the general expression "every males", we find in Gen 34:25.

The specification we find in Gen 34:19 is consistent with both the options, with the only difference that, in the case 1, the term בית would indicate the 'household' of Hamor, included his servants, and workmen. In the case 2, the same term would indicate the - strictly speaking - family of Hamor.

Answer (score 0):

The inhabitants of Shechem are still regarding Hamor as their father in Judges ch9 v28.

I suggest that "father of Shechem" in this case means "founder of the town of Shechem", and that the "sons of Hamor" are the town of Shechem as a corporate body. There is an individual called "Shechem son of Hamor" in the next chapter, so perhaps we should regard the town as having been named after him.